# C# How to simply encrypt a string with a openPGP keys

Tags: c#, encryption, bouncycastle, openpgp

I have OpenPGP `pgpkey` and `pgpid`, in C# how to simply encrypt a string using the Bouncy Castle library ?

Public Key of receiver(MPI in base64):
`BADelitpUqMZLn+bryZR5rK9J3eu+pRVFP5tpboOlIwO2vqO/rCi8VvT2TPzEJarWhyZ465NIohYCiia9vaGUEp4rsDzFnVNgpON47yPew1zCmOOofituf+X6Qlaxylm5NnO4vnRcmoF4IbGwSCqyGgGor29D75Hovwlj1q6BWHYWwAGKQ==`

Key Type of Public Key: `RSA`

Key ID of Public Key (8 bytes in hex): `02044b001cd7a551`

Answer (score 1):

This blog post shows [an example of OpenPGP encryption](http://rafayal.blogspot.fr/2009/06/pgp-encryption-with-c.html) using the Bouncy Castle library. The same author has also written about [the decryption part](http://rafayal.blogspot.fr/2009/06/pgp-decryption-with-c.html).

Comment: thanks,I see the example,but i have not  private key and password

Comment: @user1871892: Your private key is used by you to sign your messages. If you don't plan to do that then skip the "The last thing we want to do here, is sign the encrypted data itself" part of the example.